# Need to convert decimal to base 32, whats wrong ? base 32 = 0-9 A-V

Tags: base32

this is my code in c, need to convert from from decimal to base 32 .Getting strange symbols as output.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
        char * f(unsigned int num){
            static  char base[3];
            unsigned int mask=1,base32=0;
            int i,j;

            for (j=0;j<3;j++)
            for (i=0;i<5;num<<1,mask<<1){
                if (mask&num){
                    base32 = mask|base32;
                    base32<<1;
                }
                if (base32<9)   
                    base[j]=base32+'0';
                else    
                    base[j]=(char)(64+base32-9);
            }
        }
```

base 32 = 0-9 A-V

```
 int main()
                {
                    unsigned int num =100;

                    printf("%s\n",f(num));

                    return 1;
                }
            should get 34.
```

Answer (score 0):

You shift both `mask` and `num` in your loop. This means you're always checking for the same bit, just moved around. Only shift one of the values, the `mask`.

Also you're skipping the number 9 with your comparison.

Using a debugger you can easily see what's happening and how it is going wrong.